# weakly lower semi continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that W.L.S.C. (weakly  lower semi continuous) implies L.S.C. (lower     semi continuous) and 
I have a question:

If   $f_n\rightarrow f$ weakly, and  $f_n\rightarrow f$ strongly, is there any relation between $\liminf f_n$ in these cases, for example $\liminf f_n$ in weakly convergence is smaller than that of the strongly convergence?

Comment: What space are the $f_n$ living in?  What do you mean by "\liminf f_n$ in weakly convergence"?

Comment: they are in $L^2$

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see, if you write the definitions (statements) of W.L.S.C. and L.S.C. as follows:

W.L.S.C.: If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ (weakly), then $\phi(u) \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n$.

L.S.C.: If $u_n \rightarrow u$ (strongly), then $\phi(u) \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n$.

Then the implication W.L.S.C. $\Rightarrow$ L.S.C. is easy to see:

Let $u_n \rightarrow u$ then $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and using assumption of W.L.S.C. we have $\phi(u) \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n $.

Comment: But I see LSC implies WLSC

Comment: I thin you're missing $\phi$ on the RHS of your statements...